# Remove border of navbar-left and right bootstrap on mobile menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi am working on my navbar. When the navbar is in mobile view when I click and open the menu above and below the form input there looks to be like `border-bottom`

Like here

[image]

I am unable to find away to hide those two lines.

> **Question** On when in mobile view how is it possible to remove / disable
>   those border-bottom above and below form input

Codepen [Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/YWRRkv/)

```
body {
    background: url('../images/bg.png');
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

hr {
    border-top: 10px solid #444444;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-left {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}

.navbar-form {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}

.page-wrapper {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        min-width: 150px;
     }

}

.custom-nav { 
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #333333;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-brand { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-brand:hover { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home {
    border-top: 2px solid #AC3931;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home:hover, 
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home:focus {
    background-color: #AC3931;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum {
    border-top: 2px solid #F6AE2D;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum:hover, 
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum:focus {
    background-color: #F6AE2D;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog {
    border-top: 2px solid #3B910D;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog:hover, 
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog:focus {
    background-color: #3B910D;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.codeigniter {
    border-top: 2px solid #2868B7;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.codeigniter:hover, 
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.codeigniter:focus {
    background-color: #2868B7;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1040px) {
    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {

    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.home {
        border-top: none;
        border-left: 2px solid #AC3931;
    }

    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.forum {
        border-top: none;
        border-left: 2px solid #F6AE2D;
    }

    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.blog {
        border-top: none;
        border-left: 2px solid #3B910D;
    }

    .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.codeigniter {
        border-top: none;
        border-left: 2px solid #2868B7;
    }
}

.page {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    /*box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px #989898, 12px 12px 0px #6B6666;*/
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.module {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.module .module-info {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'source code pro';
}

.module .module-title {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse custom-nav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="forum" href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a class="blog" href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle codeigniter" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CodeIgniter <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </nav>
</div><!-- /.container-->
```

Comment: 1. its `box-shadow` not `border`. 2. you need to learn `how to use media query` to change/alter `CSS` properties for `devices` or at/after any particular `width`

Answer (score 1):

Put **`box-shadow: none;`** to **`<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">`** and the problem will be solved.

**Code:**

```
form.navbar-form.navbar-right {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**Codepen:** → [here](http://codepen.io/angelpolitis/pen/xOmVXG).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every ones solution

### SOLVED

When I just added box shadow none on it's own it still showed lines but darker

> There for I have had to add `border-top 0` and
>   `border-bottom 0` and it worked

```
.navbar-form {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

---

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-form{
        -webkit-box-shadow:none;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
}
```